# Maven can not find the 'main' class for my Java app

Tags: java, maven

I am new to Java and this is my first time using Maven. I have tried to build a working pom.xml file by stitching together various things I've read and copy-and-pasting them to pom.xml. This is not working.

I put my java files in this folder:

```
src/main/java/com/ollio/nlp/
```

my main class is here:

```
src/main/java/com/ollio/nlp/Main.java
```

Its package:

```
package com.ollio.nlp;
```

The code is huge and too much to repeat here, but the class begins the normal way:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String...args){
```

My pom.xml file, in total:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ollio.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>nlp</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>nlp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>com.ollio.nlp.main</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- put your configurations here -->
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-beta-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
      <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

If I run:

```
mvn package
```

I see errors such as:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.rollioapp.nlp:nlp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 32, column 15

[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 20, column 15
```

But in the end it says:

```
BUILD SUCCESS
```

but if I try:

```
java -jar target/nlp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.ollio.nlp.main
```

How do I set the main class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class names are case-sensitive. Your class is called `Main` so the manifest should be:

```
<manifest>
    <mainClass>com.ollio.nlp.Main</mainClass>
</manifest>
```